# How to match arbitrary adjacent identical strings?

Tags: python, regex

There are some repeating strings in my data that I need to find. They have a pattern that they repeat twice, and the repetitions are adjacent, with no space in between. They can have arbitrary lengths (within one line) and can contain letters, numbers and spaces. How do I use regular expressions to match such strings? Thank you.

Examples of what I want to match:

```
FooFoo
Bar 1Bar 1
X1 Y2 Z3X1 Y2 Z3
```

**Edit:** The RegEx engine I used was Python's re package. I realized this question would be more appropriate for StackOverflow, and I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Hello, where? This is a website for software related problems. Not including software means we have no idea which regex engine is used. If it's programming question, ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: While someone has presented an answer that works for you, please note that the broader purpose of this site is to build an encyclopedia of answers that benefit others. With your question lacking necessary information, such as the software you are working within, this question will be closed and then deleted. Please consider others who your question and its answer may help, and EDIT your question to add the necessary information to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your regex flavour, this does the job:

```
^(.+)\1$
```

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/nSz9ER/1)